# how to properly structure pyspark code to work with spark streaming and kafka

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code, which suppose to connect to a local kafka cluster, and run a pyspark job:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from operator import add
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
## Constants
APP_NAME = "PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount"
##OTHER FUNCTIONS/CLASSES

def main(sc):
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
if __name__ == "__main__":

   # Configure Spark
   conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
   conf = conf.setMaster("local[*]")
   sc   = SparkContext(conf=conf)
#   filename = sys.argv[1]
   # Execute Main functionality
   main(sc)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount, master=local[*]) created by __init__ at /home/ubuntu/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/hello1.py:30
```

What is the proper way to structure my code, to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't create `SparkContext` twice. If it is created inside `main` function there is no reason to pass it from outside:

```
def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
    conf = conf.setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since `StreamingContext` termination stops corresponding `SparkContext` there is no good reason to keep these two apart.

`SparkContext` has also a [`getOrCreate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate) which can be used to create new context or retrieve existing one.